# Finding node depth from Pandas dataframe for full hierarchical data

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I have a Pandas dataframe with sample hierarchical data i.e.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
"manager_id": ["A", "A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "B", "F"],
"employee_id": ["B", "C", "C", "D", "E", "E", "E", "G"]
} )
```

Given that the data consists of all the descendent relationships for each manager. For example in each manager id (e.g. "A"), the employee id comprises both the employees (e.g. "B") directly managed by manager "A" and the employees managed by employee "B" (e.g. "C", "D"). I already have a solution to create a graph in networkx ([How to generate graph from Pandas dataframe with full hierachical data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78106081/generating-graph-from-pandas-dataframe-with-full-hierachical-data)). But how do I add a column in this data that computes the depth of each manager and employee from the graph?

Intended output as below:

```
  manager_id employee_id  depth
0          A           B      1
1          A           C      2
2          B           C      1
3          A           D      1
4          C           E      1
5          A           E      3
6          B           E      2
7          F           G      1
```

Answer (score 1):

As commented in my [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78106405/16343464), you can get the absolute depth with [`topological_generations`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.topological_generations.html). Since you want the relative depth, you can subtract the depth of the `manager_id` from that of the `employee_id` (both obtained from `order` using [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)):

```
import networkx as nx

# create directed graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(data, source='manager_id', target='employee_id',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# get node generation
order = {n: i for i, l in enumerate(nx.topological_generations(G)) for n in l}
# {'A': 0, 'F': 0, 'B': 1, 'D': 1, 'G': 1, 'C': 2, 'E': 3}

# map generation on both source/target
# compute difference to get the relative depth
data['depth'] = (data['employee_id'].map(order)
                 .sub(data['manager_id'].map(order))
                 )
```

Output:

```
  manager_id employee_id  depth
0          A           B      1
1          A           C      2
2          B           C      1
3          A           D      1
4          C           E      1
5          A           E      3
6          B           E      2
7          F           G      1
```

Intermediates:

```
  manager_id employee_id  manager_id_depth  employee_id_depth  depth
0          A           B                 0                  1      1
1          A           C                 0                  2      2
2          B           C                 1                  2      1
3          A           D                 0                  1      1
4          C           E                 2                  3      1
5          A           E                 0                  3      3
6          B           E                 1                  3      2
7          F           G                 0                  1      1
```

Graph with absolute depth of the nodes and computation of the relative depth (child depth - parent depth):

[image: networkx graph with absolute depth of the nodes]